# How to retrieve posts from Google Currents using the Google API?

Tags: google-api

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to retrieve all the posts of a community of Google Currents using the Google API, in order to store them automatically somewhere else. Unfortunately, I've found nothing that allows me to achieve that so far.

Do you know any way to do that? Google API related, or not.

So far, I've looked in the Google API docs but haven't found anything truly usefull. I might need to develop a script that retrieves on its own the posts. Seems like a lot of work.

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue and what you have tried so far. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.